# React.js - Wait for updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component (`Parent`). This component (hook) has a `state` variable called `refs`. This variable is an object, which saves all `ref`s used in `Parent` component and all `Child` components like this way:

```
const [refs, setRefs] = useState({
    "ref1": ref1,
    "ref2": ref2,
    "ref3": ref3,
});
```

Please don't ask why. Actually this is needed in the current solution.

So the code of the `Parent` component is like this:

```
export default function Parent(props) {
    
    const ref1 = useRef(null);
    const ref2 = useRef(null);
    const ref3 = useRef(null);

    const [refs, setRefs] = useState({
        "ref1": ref1,
        "ref2": ref2,
        "ref3": ref3,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        updateRefs({
            "ref1": ref1,
            "ref2": ref2,
            "ref3": ref3,
        });
    },[
        ref1,
        ref2,
        ref3
    ])

    function updateRefs(updateRefs) {
        let updatedRefs = Object.assign({}, refs, updateRefs);
        setRefs(updatedRefs);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Child1
                updateRefs={updateRefs}
            />
            <Child2
                updateRefs={updateRefs}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this example the `Parent` component has 3 `ref`s. These are saved directly during the initialization of the variable `refs` as shown above. When they are assigned to a DOM element, the `useEffect` is being called to update them.

Now to my issue.
Now the `Child`s are returning their `ref`s by calling the function `updateRefs`.

This becomes a problem, when I have more than 1 Child in my `Parent` component.
Let's say `Child1` is returning `ref4` and `ref5`, while `Child2` is returning `ref6` and `ref7`.
When the `Parent` component is rendering, `Child1` is returning its `refs`. So before the update of `Child1`, the state of `refs` is still containing `ref1`, `ref2` and `ref3`. After the update, it should also contain `ref4` and `ref5`.

Now when `Child2` is returning its `refs`, the state is still unchanged despite the update of `Child1` (= `ref1`, `ref2` and `ref3`).
So `Child2` is now calling `updateRefs`, but without the previous update of `Child1`.
In the end, the state will be

```
ref1: ref1,
ref2: ref2,
ref3: ref3,
ref6: ref6,
ref7: ref7
```

instead of having all `Child` `updateRef`s:

```
ref1: ref1,
ref2: ref2,
ref3: ref3,
ref4: ref4,
ref5: ref5,
ref6: ref6,
ref7: ref7
```

Is there a way to "wait" for the updated state from `Child1` and then do the updates of `Child2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relies on the state of `refs` at the time this function was defined:

```
let updatedRefs = Object.assign({}, refs, updateRefs);
setRefs(updatedRefs);
```

So if both child components invoke this same instance of `updateRefs` then they're both using the same instance of `refs`.  This creates a race condition and whoever submits their update last wins.

State updates are queued/batched, and you can use the state setter callback to make use of the state value *at that point in the queue/batch* rather than the state value that was available when this function was defined.

For example:

```
setRefs(prev => {
  let updatedRefs = Object.assign({}, prev, updateRefs);
  return updatedRefs;
});
```

That way the second queued/batched state update (the previous "winner" of the race condition) would be using the value `prev`, which would include changes from the first queued/batched state update as well.